# Как скопировать кусок кода из HTML-документа при помощи php

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Реализовал сайт по заказу товаров. Проблема с сохранением товаров в "Мои заказы". Времени нет, нужно показать проект завтра, поэтому решил плохим способом, а именно хранить HTML-код в таблице "users".
Так вот, можно как-нибудь скопировать HTML-код, который находится в блоке с классом "cart-wrapper"

```
<div id="cart-wrapper" class="cart-wrapper">
    <!-- Содержимое корзины -->
    <div class="cart-item" data-id="01">
    ...
    </div>
    <div class="cart-item" data-id="02">
    ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Пытался сделать как-то так, но никак не получается

```
<?php
    $href = 'index.php';
    $page = file_get_contents($href);
    preg_match("/<div.*class=\"cart-wrapper\".*>(.*)<\/div>/",$page,$match);
    print_r($page);
?>
```

Comment: Смотри в сторону  simpleXml или DomDocument

Answer (score 0):

нормальный у вас путь, только несколько поправок..во первых `print_r($match);`
во вторых немного регэксп изменим

```
preg_match("/<div.*class=\"cart-wrapper\"[^>]*>(.+)<\/div>/is",$page,$match)
```

из вашего тестового куска он вроде вырезает то, что нужно. По умолчанию жадный режим, если у вас после `</div>` закрывающего корзину есть еще дивы, то выведите комментарий в конце корзины и регекспите до него, к примеру.

Comment: к сожалению, ваш код не работает, но спасибо за ответ

Comment: print_r($page); как у вас вверху в вопросе заменили на print_r($match) ?? код рабочий, просто надо суметь его применить :)